# Blender modeling: To sphere tool does not rounded the face of model

Tags: modeling

I am beginner of Blender.I faced some problem as I try to modeling the tongue. I am trying to make the face become rounded but when i use sphere tool there is nothing change neither using loopTools to circle the faces (the faces will deleted)I dont know why this happened.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?
Thank you in advanced for those who reply.

[image: My modeling]
[image: Youtube tutorial]

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution by luck. Actually i forgot to click on the adjust edit cage to modifier.

[image]

Comment: If your going to answer your own question, please make it more useful. Six words is hardly an answer. You could start by saying what modifier you are talking about. A picture of the Subsurf modifier with the button highlighted would also help.

Comment: I see.I am sorry. Because i found the solution by luck. And i tend to delete this question as I have already solved it by myself. But there is no delete button. I am quite curious so i answered this question see whether can end the question session or not. I am so sorry.